# PS4 Country Compatibility

Tags: ps4

My friend lives in Colombia, South America and I am in Canada, and I really want to get a PS4 but I am unsure if it would even be possible to play with him in CoD or even add him to my Friends List. Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Don't use that kind of language and abuse on this site

Comment: I'm the user who edited your question, and you called me some pretty nasty names. Not cool my dude.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem with you two playing together, just invite your friend to your game and have fun. The only region block that exists is for purchasing games.

Comment: Oh god! Thanks so much! But would that mean for example, If I joined a CoD match would there be a possibility that there are people from China speaking Chinese and Swedish people speaking Swedish?

Comment: There is a possibility but it is really rare. Only happen to me once.

Comment: Games try to match based on connection stability which means you will typically end up matched within the same continent and not around the world.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill you have made a mistake with this edit rejection http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/202548 I am editing out the abuse. *rolls eyes*

Comment: @Yvette you're right I thought I was rejecting the edit that put it there in the first place. EDIT: I've rollbacked the edit everything should be good now, sorry about that.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill yeh I figured that ;) all good. Some abusive flags on the post would probably be good. We're working in here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq